# Moment of inertia of uniform solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image: My Derivation]

I have derived moment of inertia of solid sphere along diameter but my textbook says that moment of inertia is:

$$\frac{2MR^2}{5}$$
What is the mistake in my derivation?

Comment: ive been trying this for a long tym and still I am not getting any other answer

Comment: Your work is hard to read. Could you either take a higher-res picture, or tex it up?

Comment: yea sure.. ill upload a high res pic.. plz wait for a few mins!

Comment: I've made an effort to solve the problem... but why have you put it on hold?

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in the second line, in the calculation of the differential mass element. The differential mass element in this case is a disc, of radius $r$  where $r = R \cos\theta$ as you have correctly used.

However, the thickness of this differential disc is **NOT** $ R d\theta$ but $Rd\theta cos\theta$. Try to wrap your head around this. $Rd\theta$ is the length of a tiny, tiny arc of radius $R$ and angle $d\theta$ and in the infinitesimal limit it can be approximated to a straight line, that is, a chord but notice that this chord is still not along the z axis (id est, the vertical axis). So, the shape that you have described is not a disc at all. It is a conical frustum instead. (You can verify this by trying to calculate the volume of the sphere using your formula. You'd see that it doesn't come to $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 $.) And the moment of inertia for a frustrum is not $\frac{mr^2}{2}$.

What you need to do is take the vertical projection of this chord, and that is where the $cos\theta$ comes in. Try the integration again with this new differential element and you will have landed at correct moment of inertia, $\frac{2}{5} MR^2$.

Comment: yea.. I integrated it and got the answer.. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can't really follow your work, but here's one way to do it.

Take the axis to be the $z$ axis. The distance of a point $\left(r,\theta,\phi\right)$ in the sphere from the $z$ axis is $r \sin \theta$, so

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int dV \rho \left(r \sin \theta\right)^2 \\
&=& \rho \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi  d\theta \int_0^R dr \ r^2 \sin \theta \ \left(r \sin \theta\right)^2 \\
&=& 2 \pi \rho \int_0^\pi d\theta \ \sin^3 \theta \int_0^R dr \ r^4  
\end{eqnarray}
$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: I don't think the OP knows multiple integration, so it's best to steer clear of derivations from definition.

Comment: I know what you mean @AritraDas, though OP is able to avoid the volume integral because he uses the moment of inertia of a cylinder. If you want to calculate the moment of inertia of a cylinder, you have to do a double integral.

Comment: No, he could avoid the double integration again by using the moment of inertia of a ring and just one integration. However, a formal derivation should be as you have done it, using 3 integrations.

Comment: That's true @AritraDas.